# Manipulating strings in C with user input and bufferzise of 80

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the word length in characters and number of occurrences of those words in a string, The input I get it from the user. Also I have to find the average length of the word. I have to print something like this:

```
5 character word occurred 5 times
9 character word occurred 2 times
average length of the word is 5.6
```

I have this so far, I just can't figure out the occurrences and the letters. The average works fine.

```
int ch;
int numWords = 0;
int numLetters = 0;
bool prevWasASpace = true; //spaces at beginning are ignored

printf("Enter a sentence: ");
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n')

{
    if (ch == ' ')
        prevWasASpace = true;
    else
    {
        if (prevWasASpace)
            numWords++;
        prevWasASpace = false;
        numLetters++;
    }
}

if (numWords > 0)
{
    double avg = numLetters / (float)(numWords);
    printf("Average word length: %.1f (C = %d, N = %d)\n", avg, numLetters, numWords);
}
else
    printf("You didn't enter any words\n");

return 0;
```

One last question, how would I enter 4000 characters of input but only take 80 at a time?, so if I entered a big string it would only do this for 80 characters at a time, but will run the statistics all together.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a way to store/save the count of words with each length.  One (somewhat crude but do-able) way to do that is with an array of ints, where the array index indicates how many letters in the word (1 letter word count goes into index [0], 2-letter word counts into index[1], etc.)  The problem with this approach is that you have to pick a maximum word length and that is how long your array will be.  But since you plan to only accept up to 80 characters, that can be your maximum word length and so you can declare your array length 80.

To limit 80 characters of input, simply count the characters as you are reading them, and break out of the loop when you hit 80.  HTH.

(Note: If your program were to continue doing other things after what you have described above, and those other things include additional input, you would have to deal with the input beyond 80 chars that you "threw away."  But since that does not appear to be part of your assignment, you can get away with being "sloppy" and ignoring that input and just exiting the program when done).

Comment: The thing I don't know how to do is how to count the characters in each word individually. I know how to count for the whole string just not each individual word, that's what's stopping me from finishing this.

Comment: A simple solution is to keep two counters for letters, one that keeps the total (as you have now) and another that gets reset to zero every time you encounter a new word.